# threejs Colladaloader: How to turn scene into object3d

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am doing augmented reality and need to add an `Object3D` to another object for rendering.

I use the `ColladaLoader` to import the object; however, the return type is a `Scene` - not what I need.

How can I convert the scene into an `Object3D`?

Here is my current code:

```
var mouse;
var mouseObject;

var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

// Need to convert the axes so that our model does not stand upside-down:
loader.options.convertUpAxis = true;

// Load the 3D collada file (robot01.dae in my example), and specify
// the callback function that is called once the model has loaded:
loader.load( 'assets/mouse_v1_model/meshes/mouse_v1_model_animated.dae', function ( collada ) {

    // Grab the collada scene data:
    mouse = collada.scene.children[0];

    // No skin applied to my model so no need for the following:
    // var skin = collada.skins[ 0 ];

    mouseObject = new THREE.Object3D();

    for (var j = 0; j < mouse.children.length; j++) {
        mouseObject.add(new THREE.Mesh(mouse.children[j].geometry, mouse.children[j].material));
    }

    mouseObject.matrixAutoUpdate = false;
    mouseObject.position.z = 100;

    // Scale-up the model so that we can see it:
    /* mouse.scale.x = mouse.scale.y = mouse.scale.z = 3.0;
     mouse.rotation.z = 360;
     mouse.rotation.x = 180;
     mouse.rotation.y = 180;
     mouse.position.x = 0;
     mouse.position.y = -10;
     mouse.position.z = 100;
     mouse.updateMatrix();*/

    //arScene.scene.add(mouseObject);

});
```

and

```
// Load the marker to use.
arController.loadMultiMarker('jsartoolkit5/examples/Data/multi/marker.dat', function(marker, markerNum) {

    window.onclick = function() {
        arScene.video.play();
    };

    // Create an object that tracks the marker transform.
    var markerRoot = arController.createThreeMultiMarker(marker);
    arScene.scene.add(markerRoot);

    for (var i=0; i<markerNum; i++) {

        markerRoot.markers[i] = mouseObject;
        markerRoot.add(markerRoot.markers[i]);
    }

    // Call arScene.renderOn on each frame,
    // it does marker detection, updates the Three.js scene and draws a new frame.
    var tick = function() {
        requestAnimationFrame(tick);

        arScene.process();
        arScene.renderOn(renderer);
    };
    tick();

});
```

Comment: You can get your objects from the scene in the loader callback if you access the loading result like this `result.children`.

Comment: I did just that; see the code snippet that I added for the question.

Comment: I added an answer with an example...

Comment: Was my answer not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a container object of type [`THREE.Group`](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/objects/Group.js) from the loaded scene object. 
 Something like this:

```
function onLoadCallback( result ){
    // Create a group object as a container
    var container = new THREE.Group();
    container.name = 'container';
    container.children = result.children;

    // Add it to your existing scene
    scene.add( container );
}

loader.load( 'assets/mouse_v1_model/meshes/mouse_v1_model_animated.dae', onLoadCallback);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make collada yourself (e.g. export from Blender), then I would really suggest you try the ThreeJS exporter (look [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters)).

Alternatively, you can take a look inside your collada (after all, it's just an XML) and add just your object to your scene like this:

```
scene.add(collada.children.YOUR_OBJECT);
```